# Отдача файлов по паролю

Tags: nginx

Может ли nginx отдавать файлы по паролю (на пример в заголовке запроса, пароли динамичные)?

Comment: отдельные вопросы задавайте, пожалуйста, отдельными вопросами

Comment: [например](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html) или [ещё](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/secure_download/)